# Multiple inputs matlab

Tags: matlab

Can you please tell me how I can get multiple inputs from user in matlab? I thought of getting an array directly, but that doesn't seem to be possible. I tried the following

```
     velocity = input('Enter the velocities you want the aircraft to have at every node with space in between(m/s)','s');
```

and later use delimiter to read the numbers between spaces. But even for that, am not sure how to use the inbuilt functions.

```
     [u,remain] = strtok(velocity);
```

If there's no way to get multiple inputs directly, how can I put the above in a loop, so that I can read all the numbers? My apologies if the qustion is very rudimentary and your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give array as input

```
>> velocity = input('Enter the velocities you want the aircraft to have at every node with space in between(m/s)','s');
Enter the velocities you want the aircraft to have at every node with space in between(m/s) [1 2 3]
>> velocity

velocity =

 [1 2 3]
```

And then can use `velocity(1), velocity(2), ...` etc.

Or Use regex if you plan to give as comma separated input

```
>> velocity = input('Enter the velocities you want the aircraft to have at every node with space in between(m/s)','s');
Enter the velocities you want the aircraft to have at every node with space in between(m/s)1,2,3
>> result=regexp(velocity,',','split')

result = 

    '1'    '2'    '3'
```

(similarly you can use space too for separating inputs)

Comment: There's a small error, I feel. The first one, doesn't give array directly. You have to remove the 's' parameter in the end of the input argument.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by:

```
result = input('prompt');
```

Matlab will prompt for your 'prompt' and you can enter for example [1 2 3]. The result will be vector with the previous numbers in it.